# Absolute value equations answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, absolute-value

I have a problem with the absolute value equation below:

[Absolute Value Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6FvP.png)

So my doubt is: Shouldn't the answer of the equation be:

-10|x-2| = $\frac{14}{10}$

Then, |x-2| = $\frac {7}{5}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! $$-6|x-2|-9=4|x-2|+5$$ it's $$|x-2|=-\frac{7}{5},$$ which has no solutions.

Comment: Is it because $-10|x-2|=14$ then, $-1|x-2| = \frac {14}{10}$ and then $|x-2|$  is multiplied by $-1$ ?

Comment: @Mike Yes, of course.

Comment: Ok. I was just taking the $-10$ to the other side along and changing the signal there, and about the absolute value, I wasn't considering the $-$ signal left,  lol.

Comment: @Mike You are welcome!